# How can I ensure that a string contains no more than 3 digits?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will validate my string. The string should

1. be 6 to 25 characters in length (any characters are allowed)
2. not contain more than 3 digits

How can this be done?

Comment: "1: Contain all character" What does this mean?

Comment: This may not be the answer youre looking for, but learning it yourself will not only give you the answer (maybe something better), but will help you teach others too: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: well it means the string can contain any character available e.g but if there are some digits its should be maximum three digits

Comment: @MarkByers I assume he wants a 6-25 character string (From A-Z) which needs to contain 1-3 digits.

Comment: Three digits together? In any position?

Comment: any position but also string can also contain special characters not only alphabets and digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3}\D*$).{6,25}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Start of string
(?=         # Assert that the following can be matched here:
 (?:\D*\d)  # Any number of non-digits, followed by one digit
 {0,3}      # (zero to three times)
 \D*        # followed by only non-digits
 $          # until the end of the string
)           # (End of lookahead)
.{6,25}     # Match 6 to 25 characters (any characters except newlines)
$           # End of string
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative lookahead assertion as:

```
^(?!.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9]).{6,25}$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/DQuIznlPx9)

which ensures that there are no 4 digits in your input.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need to exclude strings with more than three digits and those that don't comply with the length requirements.

Both do not require Regex and in fact, constructing a regex to match is tricky, as the digits may be spread around.

Use `"a string".Length` to check the number of characters.

Iterate over the characters and use `char.IsDigit` to check for the digit count.

```
public bool IsValid(string myString)
{
   if (myString.Length < 6 || myString.Length > 25)
      return false;

   int digitCount = 0;
   foreach(var ch in myString)
   {
      if(char.IsDigit(ch))
        digitCount;
   }

   return digitCount < 4;
}
```

Comment: don't you mean 'return digitCount < 4'?